# OpenVAS shows $Revision: $ instead of actual Service Version

Tags: nmap, openvas

I'm using OpenVAS-8 with nmap 7.
On the reports of OpenVAS you can see a field called "Version used". On mine it just shows `Version used: $Revision: 1369 $` or `Version used: $Revision: 69 $` but not the version.

I think there is a misinterpretation because of the Dollar-signs. Is it caused by nmap 7? The output of nmap -sV -Pn *.*.*.* is actually the same like in the versions before so there shouldn't be any parsing errors...
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVAS is using the SVN-Revision as version for the NVTs.

http://www.openvas.org/openvas-cr-56.html
"Version tag: The SVN "Revision" tag is used for the version. Therefore the script files need to be prepared for this for SVN and the script_version() command in the NVTs must be present and contain the correct "Revision" SVN tag"